# Method not allowed first API

Tags: python, api, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

been through a few web scraping tutorials now trying a basic api scraper.

This is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = 'https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/services/wxdata.svc/GetDataX'

response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

print (content)
```

comes up with method not allowed :(

Im still learning so any advice will be well recieved
cheers

Comment: The URL you're trying to GET does not allow GET requests. So you need to figure out what the correct URL is

Comment: response = requests.post(url, timeout=5) . i think post works. But u still need an authenticated session , to get data from the above url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly a problem with your URL, service doesn't allow to retrieve information. but you can check this URL, where the steps for retrieving metadata are described.
https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/services/wxdata.svc